# Flask - SQLAlchemy many to many causes sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class Show(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True, nullable=False)
    studio = db.relationship("ShowStudio", backref="show", cascade="delete")

class Studio(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    show = db.relationship("ShowStudio", backref="studio", cascade="delete")

class ShowStudio(db.Model):
    show_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Show.id, ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True)
    studio_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Studio.id, ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True)

studio = Studio(name="asd")

db.session.add(studio)
s = Show(title="a", studio=[studio])
db.session.flush()

db.session.add(s)
db.session.commit()
```

When I run it, it throws

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: Attempting to flush an item of type  as a member of collection "Studio.show". Expected an object of type  or a polymorphic subclass of this type.

I follow the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3179160/3673259). I do not understand what cause the error. Any helps are welcome.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Can you provide an example explaining the different? For me, it looks the same from the documentation.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999934/sqlalchemy-many-to-many-relationship-association-object, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447396/insert-data-in-many-to-many-relationship-in-sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There'd seem to be a little mixup between a [many to many relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) and using the [association object pattern](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) (which is a variant of many to many). Given the way you've configured your models `Show.studio` is actually a [one to many relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many) with `ShowStudio`, and so it expects a collection of `ShowStudio` objects, not `Studio`:

```
studio = Studio(name="asd")    
db.session.add(studio)

showstudio = ShowStudio(studio=studio)
# You've disabled save-update cascade, so you have to
# add the association object to the session manually!
db.session.add(showstudio)

s = Show(title="a", studio=[showstudio])
db.session.add(s)

db.session.commit()
```

For your original attempt to work you'd define a many to many relationship between `Show` and `Studio` using the table underlying `ShowStudio` as the [secondary](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.secondary):

```
class Show(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True, nullable=False)
    studio = db.relationship("Studio", secondary="show_studio",
                             back_populates="show")

class Studio(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    show = db.relationship("Show", secondary="show_studio",
                           back_populates="studio")

class ShowStudio(db.Model):
    show_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Show.id, ondelete="CASCADE"),
                        primary_key=True)
    studio_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Studio.id, ondelete="CASCADE"),
                          primary_key=True)
```

Since there's no explicit `__tablename__` in `ShowStudio` [Flask-SQLAlchemy automatically sets it for you](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/models/) to *show_studio*.